# Error Message : ORA-01841 when trying to filter records by date

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-9

I am using Oracle Database with Laravel application
I have `Record` model and its database table is `items_view` which is a Database View, now I want to get all records with `'INVH_DT'` column (which is of date type) equals to a specific date so I am using this:

```
$records = Record::where('INVH_DT', 'to_date(\'22/06/2022\' , \'DD/MM/YYYY\')' )->get();
```

but I have this error:

> Error Code : 1841 Error Message : ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, >and not be 0 Position : 46 Statement : select * from "ITEMS_VIEW" where "INVH_DT" = :p0 >Bindings : [to_date('22/06/2022' , 'DD/MM/YYYY')]
> select
> *
> from
> "ITEMS_VIEW"
> where
> "INVH_DT" = to_date('22/06/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')

I tried this statement `elect * from "ITEMS_VIEW" where "INVH_DT" = to_date('22/06/2022' , 'DD/MM/YYYY')` on Oracle SQL Developer and it works fine.
I tried other date formats like `'YYYYMMDD'` and it works fine on SQL Developer while giving the same error of Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that Laravel deals with this issue by Query builder's `whereDate` clause [Additional Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)
and this just worked as expected:

```
$records = Record::whereDate('INVH_DT', '2022-06-22')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Laravel, but the resulting SQL command looks like this:

```sql
select * from "ITEMS_VIEW" where "INVH_DT" = :p0
```

where the `:p0` parameter is replaced with `to_date('22/06/2022' , 'DD/MM/YYYY')`. It will not work that way.

Maybe try this:

```php
$records = Record::where("to_char(INVH_DT, 'DD/MM/YYYY')", '22/06/2022')->get();
```

Comment: didn't work too it returns `ORA-00904: "TO_CHAR(INVH_DT, 'DD/MM/YYYY')": invalid identifier Position`
I solved it by using Laravel's `whereDate()`.